# Sanctuary spell and Using magic Items that cause damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, attack

Currently have a character who has the Sanctuary spell and a wand of magic missile (also other damaging magic items)

If a character uses a item e.g. wand of magic missile to damage a enemy does this constitute a "Attack" causing the Sanctuary spell to drop? (WoMM a bit different because no attack is performed just damage)

> If the warded creature makes an Attack or casts a spell that affects an enemy creature, this spell ends.

Simplified does using magic items that don't use the "attack" term or cast spells through themselves drop sanctuary?

Comment: Note that the [*Sanctuary*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sanctuary) spell has been revised in an erratum. The revised version of the sentence you quoted above now reads "If the warded creature makes an attack, casts a spell that affects an enemy, or deals damage to another creature, this spell ends."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Description of [Wand of Magic Missiles](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/wand-of-magic-missiles) states:

> This wand has 7 charges. While holding it, you can use an action to expend 1 or more of its charges to **cast the magic missile spell** from it.

Emphasis mine.

Description is pretty clear that *"you"* casts spell from the wand, so while you are right it does not count as an attack, Sanctuary ends because character using this wand casts a spell.

---

On the other end o the spectrum is [Ring of Shooting Stars](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-shooting-stars). It's first use allows user to cast a spell. Second one, though:

> Ball Lightning. You can expend 2 charges as an action to create one to four 3-foot-diameter spheres of lightning. The more spheres you create, the less powerful each sphere is individually.
>
> *(...)*
>
> When a creature other than you comes within 5 feet of a sphere, **the sphere discharges lightning** at that creature and disappears.

Here it is pretty clear that user is not attacking, not casting a spell, and it is the sphere that hurts the opponent, not the ring bearer. Thus, Sanctuary continues.

Bottom line: There is no fast and easy answer that applies to all items and all uses of the same item. You'll have to read the item's description.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply just checking does the character cast the spell or does he use the magic missile wand that casts the spell?

Comment: @Troommate description is pretty clear that "you" casts spell from the wand.

Comment: Great thanks for help was still trying to get my head around it.

Comment: Guess English is not your first language?  I had similar issues at first.

Comment: While this answers the question for a Wand of Magic Missiles specifically, I believe there *are* other magic items that can deal damage or cause other negative effects without casting a spell or making an attack, such as a [Ring of Shooting Stars](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-shooting-stars). It would be good to cover that case as well in your answer.